# Does Pithru Tharpana in both Kasi & Rameswaram reduces evil effects of the doer?

Tags: rituals, sraddha, pitru, pilgrimage

Legend says that doing pithru tharpana in Kasi and from there directly going to Rameswaram and performing the pithru tharpana is good and it reduces evil effects of the doer. Any substantiative evidence for this??

Comment: What is the substantial evidence you are looking for?

Comment: Are u asking whether those two places are good places to perform Pitru related works or not?

Comment: @Rickross Everybody knows that these two places are good to perform pitru tharpana. Undestand the meaning of the question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Some matters are hearsays and they are getting  pass on to the next generation. Doing pithru  tharpana in a ordinary river or house has its own significance. Kasi and Rameswaram are famous for this pithru tharpaman as per legends whether you are aware or not . If it has been mentioned in any scriptures.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Gaya is also a very very suspicious place to perform Pitru Tarpanam, especially Pinda Pradhanam. It is said that a son should perform Pinda Pradhanam at least once in a lifetime. But I have not heard that doing Pitru Tarpanam brings evil effects to the doer.

Comment: God forgive spelling :)  to the very very auspicious place..

Comment: Then it is not answerable. We can only cite what the scriptures say on the topic. @ParthasarathyRaghavan But it seems you are not looking for simply scriptural quotes.

Comment: @Rickross Looking for exact scriptural  quotes with proper answer.